# LSI MegaRAID SAS hwraid on 16.04

Tags: raid

Ubuntu 16.04 is having trouble working with a LSI MegaRAID SAS 9240-4i hardware RAID controller. Has anybody gotten this card to work, or a related model?

Here are some details of what I'm experiencing:

```
# lspci | grep Mega
03:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] [1000:0073] (rev 03)

# dmesg | grep mega
[    4.654760] megasas: 06.810.09.00-rc1
[    4.655001] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: FW now in Ready state
[    4.655029] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: firmware supports msix : (0)
[    4.655031] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: current msix/online cpus : (1/12)
[    4.655033] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: RDPQ mode     : (disabled)
[    4.677786] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: Failed to init firmware
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
This controller should work fine with Linux according to [here](http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS). Additionally, after rebooting Windows after booting a Linux LiveCD, the MegaRAID Storage Manager pops up to complain about a firmware error. This has never occurred before and only happens after booting Linux. I checked the firmware version and it is quite outdated. Hence, I now suspect that a firmware update may solve my problem. I'll try as soon as I updated my backups.

Edit 2:
Upgrading the controller's firmware did not change anything. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar issue with ubuntu server 17.04 and an LSI 9240-8i. It turned out that I had installed ubuntu in UEFI mode, but my motherboard was trying to load the BIOS firmware from the controller. I received the exact same dmesg output described in the question.

I resolved the issue by changing my bios to prefer UEFI firmware from PCI-E devices.

After that, the ubuntu drivers loaded correctly and my disks were available from the os.

Changing my bios settings also disable the RAID GUI that could load during boot, but I didn't need that since I had already set my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have a PC with the same (or similar) RAID controller (with only one disk attached), but it seems to work for me:

```
root@mypc:~# lspci | grep -i raid
04:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] (rev 03)
root@mypc:~# dmesg | grep mega
[    1.595487] megasas: 06.810.09.00-rc1
[    1.601883] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: FW now in Ready state
[    1.601907] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: firmware supports msix    : (0)
[    1.601909] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: current msix/online cpus  : (1/4)
[    1.601910] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: RDPQ mode : (disabled)
[    1.651293] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: controller type   : iMR(0MB)
[    1.651296] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: Online Controller Reset(OCR)  : Enabled
[    1.651297] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: Secure JBOD support   : No
[    1.651300] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: megasas_init_mfi: fw_support_ieee=67108864
[    1.651302] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: INIT adapter done
[    1.651453] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: Jbod map is not supported megasas_setup_jbod_map 4941
[    1.699292] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: pci id        : (0x1000)/(0x0073)/(0x1028)/(0x1f78)
[    1.699294] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: unevenspan support    : no
[    1.699296] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: firmware crash dump   : no
[    1.699297] megaraid_sas 0000:04:00.0: jbod sync map     : no

root@mypc:~# uname -r
4.4.0-38-generic
```

However, shutdown seems to leave the disk in an unclean state and I have to run fsck on reboot.